# Agrupar valores de colunas diferentes em uma só, separados por vírgula

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho o seguinte `select`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORGAO, UNIDADE FROM TESTE
```

Onde é gerado o seguinte resultado:

```
Órgao Unidade
1     2
1     3
1     4
1     5
```

São retornados 4 registros de mesmo órgão, porém com unidades diferentes. O que eu queria é que me retornasse somente uma linha com 2 colunas, a primeira órgão (1) e a segunda Unidade (2,3,4,5) separados por vírgulas.

Como posso fazer isso? Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso que você está tentando fazer não parece ser lá uma boa ideia, e normalmente quando se vai por esse caminho, é sinal de que há algo errado na sua compreensão acerca da finalidade da consulta ou do resultado gerado.

Entretanto, supondo que seja exatamente isso o que você quer. Você poderia usar o `LISTAGG` do oracle dessa forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    orgao,
    LISTAGG(unidade, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY unidade) AS unidades
FROM TESTE
GROUP BY orgao;
```

Fonte: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques

Comment: deu certo obrigado